# How to use a List of a class from a custom assembly in SSRS

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have a class called InvoiceInterest that implements a static method GetInvoices returning a List of InvoiceInterest. This class also includes various other static methods of use to calculate the interest of an invoice such as CompoundInterest which returns the compounded interest for a time period.

I need to use this class in SSRS to develop a report on the invoices returned. I've already been able to retrieve data and display it in SSRS. I can easily call CompoundInterest to show the compounded interest, but CompoundInterest only returns a decimal value. I need to display the list of invoices for a customer using GetInvoices to return the List of InvoiceInterest and display the various properties in this class in a tabular form.

Question: How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to create a [custom data processing extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152816%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) which calls your class and processes the list like a dataset. We did this with an ASP.Net RESTful web services layer we built so that we could call the controllers directly from Reporting Services.

It might be overkill for your requirements but if you absolutely need to treat your list as a datasource then this will work. There are plenty of examples on the internet to get you started.